Objects are falling outside instead of inside when using rigid body
I have a text converted into a mesh. I want a bunch of cones to fall into the hole in the text. When I use rigid body, all the cones end up outside the text instead of inside. How can I get them to collect inside the text?
What I'm trying to do is to fill a logo with objects, like lots of cones. The logo is extruded but has no top face. They should then lie still in the logo, just looking natural.
The file: 


Check your face orientation:

Blue is good, red is bad.

Select all cones
Press Tab to change to Edit Mode
Press A to select all
Press Shift+N to recalculate normals
In Object Mode select all cones, choose Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry
Select your text and all cones, then press S, type 100, press Ctrl+A > Apply Scale

The scale of your objects was ridiculous low. Blender simulations don't like "wrong" or extreme scales.
The result:


I flipped the normals but the cones ends up outside the text instead of inside still!

Thank you!! What are ideal scales for Blender simulations?

"normal" sizes for rigid bodies. So like the default cube. For cloth better 10x or 20x of that size.
